# Nuxt 3 useRoute import cannot find

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am using latest nuxt version and when I tried to use the `useRoute` method is triggers a `"Cannot Find name useRoute"` but it works, so I would like to know what could I be missing

```vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const routes = useRoute();
 </script>
 
 <template>
 </template>
```

My `package.json` has these versions

```
    "devDependencies": {
      "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
      "@types/node": "^18",
      "nuxt": "^3.6.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@nuxt/image": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
      "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.8.0",
      "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^5.3.0",
      "nuxt-icon": "^0.4.1",
      "nuxt-swiper": "^1.1.1"
    }
```

The `useRoute` autocompletes fine in `pages/index.vue` but if I try to use it in different vue file or directory inside pages it triggers the same error

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*).

Answer (score 4):

I finally was able to "fix the problem", the issue was an extension from vscode that was triggering this ts error. This is the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=praburangki.nuxt-snippets just to let you know

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me crazy.

Comment: I ran into same error, and fixed by re-installing Vue Language Features (Volar) extension.